# Action that return PartialViewResult , must return string (HTML CODE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Initial:

```
public ActionViewResult Action_ASDA(Model model)
{
...
...
return PartialView("My_Model_View",model);
}
```

ok .. and now I need this function to return HTML code (same function , but I need to return as string the HTML)

```
public string Action_ASDA(Model model)
{
...
...
// HTML RESPONSE
Response.Clear();
Action_ASDA(model).ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
Action_ASDA(model).ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
return Response.ToString().Replace("System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper", string.Empty);

}
```

Where show "..." are code for model generation and completation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return HTML string, you can use:

```
string html = "<div>Hello, this is div</div>";
return Content(html, "text/xml");
```

Comment: I have a VIEW who is generated dynamically from model. If you will tell me how to set value for your variabile "html" , will be ok.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. If you are using Partial Views, why not return a `PartialView` like you did at first?

Comment: Because I need another solution to refresh my partial view automatic.

Comment: `PartialView` does just that. It renders a piece of HTML and returns it in the response. I'm guessing you are making an Ajax call to refresh a region in your site?

Comment: Yes , I`m using Ajax Call AND I NEED to get html code rendered , because in ajax call i need this:    success: function(html) 
        { 
            //$("#myView").html(html);

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what `return PartialView` does.